# Largest determinant of a real $3\times 3$-matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

What is the largest determinant of a real  $3\times 3$-matrix with entries from the interval $[-1,1]$ ? A result of John Williamson says that the largest value is equal to $4$, if the entries are just either $1$ or $-1$. Is this still true for all values in $[-1,1]$ ? For complex matrices with entries $|a_{ij}|\le 1$ 
it is not true. We have $|\det(A)|\le 3\sqrt{3}$, and equality can be attained with a Vandermonde type of matrix containing the third roots of unity.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in the real case, and even for $n\times n$ matrices, the maximum is achieved when the entries are taken from the set $\{-1,1\}$, but I don't know a good reference offhand. Maybe a treatment of Hadamard matrices would cover this question. The opening paragraph of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix backs me up.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The determinant is (up to sign and a factor of $6$) the volume of a tetrahedron having the origin and the three column vectors as vertices. Moving one vertex further from the plane determined by the other three vertices increases this volume. By convexity of the cube, among the farthest points is at least one vertex. Thus the result for $[-1,1]$ is the same as for $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: +1. Your argument extends nicely to the $n\times n$ case: starting with the optimal $[-1,1]$-matrix, by fixing the other $n-1$ column vectors, the determinant is a linear function of the remaining column. By convexity, the maximum must also occur at some vertex. Thus the result for $[-1,1]$ is the same as for $\{-1,1\}$.